# How do I upload csv files to Heroku Postgres?

Tags: csv, heroku

I have a very basic question. I created a Metabase Heroku app:

http://walmart-store-sales-forecast.herokuapp.com

I see that there's a sample dataset. I want to be able to upload csv data from https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/data to the app so that I can query the data using PostgreSQL and create data visualizations using Metabase. Can someone walk me through the steps of uploading the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can follow a guide on Google. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/.

You'll need a postrgresql client. I use pgadmin which is free.

Comment: Perfect! This helps a lot. I also found an article on Heroku that talks about importing Postgresql database to Heroku. I'll post the link below.

Comment: welcome to SFSE! while there is some debate on it https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/can-we-please-stop-closing-questions-about-heroku, you might consider posting this to stackoverflow which has a larger heroku following, and definitely a large postgres community.

Answer (score 1):

I realize Heroku already has a post addressing this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

Basically, I need to create a dump file of the Postgresql database from my local machine. Then, use cloud storage like Amazon S3 to upload the dump file. Then restore the database on Heroku. I didn't try this yet, but this seems to be the solution to my question.